# How to log into WordPress admin in MAMP

Tags: login

New to MAMP, but had no issues with installation and viewing the WordPress site I pulled down from my server. However, can’t figure out to log into the admin side of my site. Here’s what I’ve tried, and the results:

Setting: Web Server > Document Root > Sites

1. localhost:8888 = displays website with no issues
2. http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/ = Not Found page
3. Both localhost:8888/mysitename/wp-admin/ and http://localhost:8888/mysitename/wp-admin redirects to https://localhost:8888/mysitename/wp-admin/ then Secure Connection Failed An error occurred during a connection to localhost:8888. SSL
   received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
   Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

Everything I’ve read makes it sound easier than this. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Go to MAMP pro and click on the localhost icon (it should be the top of the list) then to the right there will be a series of tabs - the first one being "General"

The second section down in that tab will show the "Document root" path. You can define where the files/dirs are located there.

Suugest to create a dir called "sites" in there create as many dirs as needed/whenever needed - but - point the root path at the (site) dir.

From that point on the address should be localhost/sites/**whatever the site dir name is

EG: localhost/sites/samplesite

**If you add the dir to the localhost dir - it will then show as

localhost/samplesite

Comment: The question sounds like it's having problems with an HTTPS redirect, though, not the actual path.

Answer (score 0):

Same here

I am also looking for a solution for this but have not been able to find the right solution that works properly yet

Versions:

> ```
> macOS Catlina: 10.15.7 (19H524)
>
> MAMP: 5.7
>
> Firfox: 89.0.2 (64-bit)
>
> WordPress: 5.7.2
> ```

[image]

Comment: Can you try `openssl s_client -connect localhost:8888` ? That should give you some technical details of the SSL connection you've got set up, which will hopefully tell you what the problem is, e.g. make sure it negotiates at least TLS 1.2.

Comment: (But this is probably Apache configuration not actually a WordPress issue, and you've posted this as an answer to a question when it's really a new similar question.)

Comment: I suspect the problem is that port 8888 is HTTP, not HTTPS. Did you type https:// or http;//? If you typed HTTP then it looks like the admin site code is insisting on using HTTPS - does MAMP provide an HTTPS port? If not, you might have to put a hack in wp-config to make WordPress think it's being served over HTTPS when it isn't. However in that case it's really a problem with MAMP so you should ask them for help too.

Comment: @Rup
after running `openssl s_client -connect localhost:8888`



`CONNECTED(00000005)
4499389888:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 293 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---`

Comment: Yes, that's what you get for an HTTP port not HTTPS. You need to use http:// with port 8888 not https://.

Comment: Thanks @Rup 
Will try

Comment: If you're entering http:// but that's redirecting you to https:// then you probably have `define( 'FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true );` in your wp-config. I'd guess you can't use that with MAMP.